# Font awesome icons loading late in Angular 4 app

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I'm using an spinning Font awesome icon in the index.html of an Angular application while it loads the main component. The code is:

```
<app-root>
  <div style="width: 100%; padding-top: 50px; text-align: center">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
    Loading...
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

The problem is that, sometimes, it seems that the app doesn't load the Font awesome CSS and it looks like this:

[image: Angular not loading CSS icon]

Right now, I'm loading the Font Awesome CSS in the `[styles]` section of the `.angular-cli.json` file. But I included it in the app index.html file and the result is the same.

Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load your icons from a faster CDN directly in your head and see if it's help. add in your head tag :

`<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I did it and it seems that it works now. The funny thing is that I started the app putting the CSS in index.html and I changed it to the 'styles' section of the Angular CLI configuration because it started showing the weird character of the picture above. But, perhaps I was loading it from the local filesystem instead of a CDN... Anyway, thanks!